# Use a contrapositive proof to show that $mn$ is a perfect square if $m$ and $n$ are

Tags: proof-verification, square-numbers

Definition: $a\in \Bbb Z$ is a perfect square if there is a $b\in\Bbb Z$ and $a = b^2$

To prove: if $m$ and $n$ are perfect squares, then $mn$ is a perfect square.

I know that this can most easily be proved with a direct proof. I want to prove this using contrapositive. Is the below valid, and if not, what would be? Also, tips on correctness of how I wrote it would be appreciated.

Proof: by contrapositive

Assume $mn$ is not a perfect square. Let $b$, $c$ $\in \Bbb Z$ where $m \ne b^2$, $n \ne c^2$. Then $mn \ne b^2c^2 \ne (bc)^2$. QED.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not entirely correct. As it is, you proved that $mn\neq (bc)^2$, for very specific $b$ and $c$ This is not at all close to a full proof.

To prove that $mn$ not a perfect square $\implies $ either $m$ or $n$ is not a perfect square, here is something you could do:
Using the [fundamental theorem of airithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) 
$$mn=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_k^{r_k}\text{ not a perfect square}\iff \text{ at least one of the $r_i$ is odd}.$$
We may say without loss of generality that $r_1$ is odd. This means that $m$ and $n$ cannot both have an even number of $p_1$'s in their prime factorization, i.e. one of them has an odd number of $p_1$'s in its prime factorization. This is (as we said) equivalent to one of them not being a perfect square.  This proves the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using here the contrapositive of $p \wedge q \Rightarrow r$ which is $\sim r \Rightarrow  \sim(p \wedge q) \equiv (\sim p)  \vee (\sim q) $. We have

If $mn$ is not a perfect square then either $m$ is not a perfect square or $n$ is not a perfect square.